# Prove a compact subset of a covering space contains a finite number of preimages

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, solution-verification, compactness, covering-spaces

Let $p:\widetilde{X} \to X$ be a covering map, $K$ a compact subset of $\widetilde{X}$, and $x$ an element of $X$. Prove that $K\cap p^{-1}(\{x\})$ is finite.

Let $x\in X$ be fixed. Since $p$ is a covering map, it is possible to construct a collection of slices $\{V_\alpha\}$ of $K$ such that $\{V_\alpha\}$ is a partition of $K$, and for each $V_\alpha$ there is a unique point $v\in V_\alpha$ such that $p(v)=x$. Equivalently, we may say that the intersection $V_\alpha \cap p^{-1}(\{x\})$ will be a singleton set for each $V_\alpha$.

Clearly the collection $\{V_\alpha\}$ will be an open cover of $K$, but since $K$ is compact there will be a finite subcover $\{V_i : 1\leq i \leq n\} \subset \{V_\alpha\}$ which contains $K$. Hence the union over $i$ of each $V_i \cap p^{-1}(\{x\})$ will be a finite union of singleton sets, and will therefore be finite. $\Box$

Is this correct?

Comment: I was learning covering spaces just a couple of days ago, and to me it is not obvious how would you do such a partition $\{V_\alpha\}$ as in your second paragraph. I would imagine that indeed one should start with some partition, but perhaps more explicitly take a partition $\{U_\alpha\}$ of $X$, lift it up to $\{V_{\alpha\beta}\}$ where $V_{\alpha\beta}$ is homeomorphic to $U_\alpha$  for each $\beta$, and take a finite subcover $V_i$.

Comment: That sounds like it's more technically correct to me. I was more thinking of just "slicing" the preimage $p^{-1}(\{x\})$ into singleton sets (could be infinitely many slices) then partition $\tilde{X}$ so that each partition contains one slice. However, as you point out, this might require additional properties on $\tilde{X}$, such as $\tilde{X}$ being Hausdorff? Not 100% sure I can get away with declaring such a partition simply exists.

Comment: no idea, to be honest. You may have a better imagination, whereas I don't have a good feeling of covering spaces, so prefer to do everything by the book there

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \in X$. If $p^{-1}(x)\cap K = \emptyset$, then this is obviously finite and we are done. Otherwise, for each $x \in p(K)$, there exists a neighbourhood $V_x$ of $x$ such that $p^{-1}(V_x) = \bigcup_{i \in I_x}U_i$, where the $U_i$ are disjoint open subsets of $\tilde{X}$ homeomorphic to $V_x$. Then $K \subseteq p^{-1}(\bigcup_{x \in p(K)}V_x)$ = $\bigcup_{x \in p(K)}p^{-1}(V_x)$ = $\bigcup_{x \in p(K)}\bigcup_{i \in I_x}U_i$. Hence $\{U_i : i \in I_x, x \in p(K)\}$ is an open cover of $K$. By compactness, there exists a subcover $\{U_1,...,U_m\}$ of $K$. The restriction of $p$ to each $U_i$ is by definition a homeomorphism onto $p(U_i)$, so each $U_i$ contains at most one element of $p^{-1}(x)$. Thus, $p^{-1}(x) \cap K = \bigcup_{i=1}^{m}p^{-1}(x) \cap U_i$ is finite.

Comment: For me this seems to be a very "dense" (probably because I haven't studied it yet) Proof. Can we say that if $K$ is not disjoint with $p^{-1}(x)$ then $K$ is a covering of $p^{-1}(x)$ and hence every covering of $K$ is a covering of $p^{-1}(x)$ (I believe this is false) and since every open cover has a finite subcover for $K$ compact, $p^{-1}(x) \cap K$ is also finite (this may also be a mistake in my understanding/reasoning)                                   If you could tell me where I am wrong it would be a lot helpful

Comment: @Aname You can't assume that $p^{-1}(x)$ is contained in $K$, although this doesn't really matter because you only need to establish that $p^{-1}(x) \cap K$ is finite. As for the second part of your question, you can't show that $p^{-1}(x) \cap K$ is finite by referring to an arbitrary finite subcover of $K$, since it cannot be assumed that $p^{-1}(x)$ has finite intersection with each open set in the subcover. To establish this latter property, you need to use the fact that a covering map ensures the existence of a local homeomorphism onto a neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: Ohh I see, thank you!